# Build a tree given only a list of parent-child relationships in Python

Tags: python, tree

I have a list of parent-child relationship as the following example: (`node0 -> node1` means that `node0` is the parent of `node1`)

```
node0 -> node1
node1 -> node2
node1 -> node3
node0 -> node4
```

What I want to construct is a dictionary that captures the tree relationships; where each parent node maps to a dictionary containing its children, and if a node is a leaf node, it will just maps to an empty list. Meaning out of this list I'd get:

`{node0:{node1:{node2:[], node3:[]}, node4:[]}}`

What's the best way for me to approach this?

Comment: Why an empty list instead of an empty dict? In addition, SO does not seem to be a platform to help complete your work, you should give your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: I didn't get to design the standard, I just have to follow an existing data format. As for what I've tried, I'm looking at the `anytree` package, but trying to convert the output formats available into what I need

Comment: What is `->` here? What is the input format? What is the problem you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by registering all nodes in one flat dictionary, and reuse those values also for nesting.

However, there should be no lists involved. All values associated with keys will be dictionaries.

To determine what is the root, find out which node is never used as a child.

```
edges = [
    ("node0", "node1"),
    ("node1", "node2"),
    ("node1", "node3"),
    ("node0", "node4")
]

nodes = {}
root = next(iter(set(start for start, _ in edges) - set(end for _, end in edges)))
for start, end in edges:
    nodes.setdefault(start, {})[end] = nodes.setdefault(end, {}) 

tree = { root: nodes[root] }
print(tree)
```